# SAPUI5 multiple Aggregation Binding

Tags: xml, view, binding, sapui5, aggregation

As an initial data set, I have an XML list that can have multiple sublists. This list should be set up dynamically using SAPUI5.
1. The first list should be a SAPUI5 list which should display the names.
2. Then the Selection Values should be displayed as SAPUI5 SegmentedButtons.
3. When the user presses the last button of the SegmentedButton, a drop-down list should show the matching subvalues.

I did the first two points in XML.view. And that works fine.
But I do not get the dropdown lists filled. How do I get the dropdown list filled?

In addition, there are two different types. If the type is "qualitative", the user gets the SegmentedButtons displayed.
If it is of the "quantitative" type, the user only gets an empty input field.

[See here for Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjfOm.png)

Dataset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets>
     <Rowset>
         <Row>
             <Name>Taste</Name>
             <Type>qualitative</Type>
             <ID>1</ID>
             <Selection>
                <Row><Value>good</Value></Row>
                <Row><Value>acceptable</Value></Row>
                <Row><Value>unacceptable</Value></Row>
            </Selection>
         </Row>
         <Row>
             <Name>Smell</Name>
             <Type>qualitative</Type>
             <ID>2</ID>
             <Selection>
                <Row><Value>good</Value></Row>
                <Row><Value>unacceptable</Value>
                    <Selection>
                        <Row><Subvalue>like fish</Subvalue></Row>
                        <Row><Subvalue>like socks</Subvalue></Row>
                    </Selection>
                </Row>
            </Selection>
         </Row>
         <Row>
             <Name>Weight</Name>
             <Type>quantitative</Type>
             <ID>3</ID>
         </Row>
         <Row>
             <Name>Appearance</Name>
             <Type>qualitative</Type>
             <ID>4</ID>
             <Selection>
                <Row><Value>good</Value></Row>
                <Row><Value>acceptable</Value></Row>
            </Selection>
         </Row>
     </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

main.view.xml

```
<List 
id="List"
headerText="List" 
items="{Result>/Rowset/Row/}" >
<InputListItem label="{Result>Name}">

    <SegmentedButton selectedButton="none" items="{Result>Selection/Row/}" visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'qualitative' }">
        <items>
            <SegmentedButtonItem key="{Result>Value}" text="{Result>Value}" />
        </items>
    </SegmentedButton>

    <Select
        visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'qualitative' }" 
        items="{Result>Selection/Row/Selection/Row/}">
        <core:Item key="{Result>Subvalue}" text="{Result>Subvalue}" />
    </Select>

    <Input value="" visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'quantitative' }" />
</InputListItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do ElementBinding against your Select control on Segmented Button "SelectionChange" event. This will change all the binding references of your Select control, so your "visible" condition will fail. So you need to set it to "true" or "false" manualy in the event. But I think this is not a problem, because if the user did a selection in a segmented button, it is because it is "qualitative".

So the snippet [here](https://jsbin.com/sosowecasu/edit?html,output)

```
  <List 
    id="List"
    headerText="List" 
    items="{Result>/Rowsets/Rowset/Row}" >
    <InputListItem label="{Result>Name}">

        <SegmentedButton selectedButton="none" items="{path:'Result>Selection/Row', templateShareable: true}" visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'qualitative' }" selectionChange="onSegBtnSelected">
            <items>
                <SegmentedButtonItem key="{Result>Value}" text="{Result>Value}" />
            </items>
        </SegmentedButton>

        <Select
            visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'qualitative'}" 
            items="{path:'Result>', templateShareable: true}">
            <core:Item key="{Result>Subvalue}" text="{Result>Subvalue}" />
        </Select>

        <Input value="" visible="{= ${Result>Type} === 'quantitative' }" />
    </InputListItem>
  </List>
```

And here the event handler

```
  onSegBtnSelected(oEvent){
    var oSegBtn = oEvent.getParameters().item;
    var oBindingPath = oSegBtn.getBindingContext("Result").getPath();
    if(this.getView().getModel("Result").getProperty(oBindingPath + "/Selection")){
      var oSelect = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getContent()[1];
      oSelect.bindElement("Result>" + oBindingPath + "/Selection/Row");
      oSelect.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks! That helped me alot.
However, the console still throws the templateShareable error.
Do you have a solution for this? https://jsbin.com/dohomefumo/edit?html,console,output (JSBIN Example)

Comment: The template shareable error won't broke your app. So don't worry. However, if you want to get rid of it, just do `templateShareable:true` in your bindings, both in the SegmentedButton and the Select control. Check out my answer, I have edit it with it.

Comment: And, if my answer helped you, remember to Select the answer as valid and up-vote as decribed in [the stackoverflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so it can help others with the same problem